# Left Join anidado y case en sequelize para mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize

Estoy intentando pasar un sql query a orm sequelize.

Tengo los modelos de cada uno, puedo agregar, actualizar y eliminar dentro de cada tabla de MYSQL.

Pero no logro hacer un sql con varios left join y un case anidado.

Espero puedan ayudarme por que aunque he leído la documentación la verdad me siento bloqueado en esta parte. Y es precisamente en el hecho de convertir esta query que si funciona en una query para orm. Es decir como estruturar esta query dentro de un Customers.findAll()

```sql
select bpl.id, v.plate, pl.name, case when bpl.type = 0 then 'Acumula' else 'Redime' end, bpl.points, bpl.createdAt
from be_parking_logs as bpl left join vehicles as v
    on bpl.vehicle_id = v.id
left join parking_lots as pl
    on bpl.parking_id = pl.id
where bpl.customer_id = '46'
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que estoy viendo en tu query es que en el momento que realizas el **case**, todo bien con la sentencia **case**, el hecho de que no te funcione es que probablemente te haga falta agregar el keyword **AS** para darle nombre a esa columna que intentas mostrar.
De todas maneras te dejo un link en donde puedes ver de mucho mejor manera lo que trato de decirte: [MySQL select statement with CASE or IF ELSEIF? Not sure how to get the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result)

Comment: En esto tienes toda la razón Jipson, pero creo que no me exprese bien. El inconveniente que tengo es precisamente en el hecho de convertir esta query que si funciona en una query para ORM. Es decir como estruturar esta query dentro de un Customers.findAll()

Comment: Ah ok entiendo, en ese caso tienes dos opciones.
La primera y en mi opinión personal sería el que debes usar es un **Raw Query**, esta opción te permite pasarle directamente el query que necesitas se ejecute, aparte tiene una opción bastante buena que es de mapear a un objeto o modelo para que te traiga los campos que quieras.

Comment: La segunda opción es la que mencionas de estructurar la query con el método **findAll()**, esta opción por la documentación he visto tiene un montón de propiedades y operadores ya pre-definidos pero es complicado con lo que buscas pero no imposible ya que existe la propiedad **includes** dentro del findAll() con la que le dice a sequelize los inner join que quireas, aparte con el atributo **attributes** puedes añadir una sentencia **CASE** dentro del select, es decir, dentro del findAll()

Comment: Espero te sea de ayuda todo lo que mencioné. Te dejo más info en los siguientes links:
[Link para el CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462446/how-to-select-case-query-in-sequelize)
[Link para el include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460270/how-to-make-join-queries-using-sequelize-on-node-js)